# Couldn't find any package by regex 'libXss.so.1

Tags: 12.04

I am using ubuntu 12.04. after  `sudo apt-get install libXss.so.1`, taking the error `Couldn't find any package by regex 'libXss.so.1'`.

Could you help me about what to do next?

Comment: What are you trying to install(why do you need this package)?

Comment: Just type sudo apt-get install libXss[TAB] to find out if there exists a library by that name. Don't type the entire name of the library.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include what you're trying to achieve here in the first place (big picture!). You appear to attempt asking `apt-get` to install a non-existing package. Maybe you just need to know what package the file `libXss.so.1` belongs to? But I think you're just showing a tiny portion of what your problem really is.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to install a filename and not a package. In cases like this, use `apt-cache search ...` to find the right *package* name. In this case:

```
$ apt-cache search libXss
libxss-dev - X11 Screen Saver extension library (development headers)
libxss1 - X11 Screen Saver extension library
libxss1-dbg - X11 Screen Saver extension library (debug package)
```

So you probably want to install `libxss1`:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
```